# How to convert float to fixed point decimal in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, decimal, precision

I have some library function `foo`, that returns a floating point value with two decimal places (representing a price). I have to pass to to other function `bar` which expects a Decimal with fixed point for two decimal places.

```
value = foo() # say value is 50.15
decimal_value = decimal.Decimal(value) # Not expected. decimal_value contains Decimal('50.14999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375')
bar(decimal_value) # Will not work as expected

# One possible solution
value = foo() # say value is 50.15
decimal_value = decimal.Decimal(str(round(value,2))) # Now decimal_value contains Decimal('50.15') as expected
bar(decimal_value) # Will work as expected
```

#### Question:

How to convert arbitrary float to fixed Decimal point with 2 decimal places? And without intermediate string conversion using `str`.

I am not worried about the performance. Just want to confirm if intermediate str conversion is the pythonic way.

#### Update: Other Possible Solutions

```
# From selected answer
v = 50.15
d = Decimal(v).quantize(Decimal('1.00'))

# Using round (Does not work in python2)
d = round(Decimal(v), 2)
```

Comment: I like the `round` solution, as its easier to read and write than the `quantize`-base solution. But bear in mind it only works on Python 3: on Python 2, `round`ing a `Decimal` instance gives a `float` back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Decimal.quantize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize):

> Return a value equal to the first operand after rounding and having the exponent of the second operand.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(50.15)
Decimal('50.14999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375')
>>> Decimal(50.15).quantize(Decimal('1.00'))
Decimal('50.15')
```

Unlike the bad `str` approach, this works for any number:

```
>>> decimal.Decimal(str(50.0))
Decimal('50.0')
>>> decimal.Decimal(50.0).quantize(decimal.Decimal('1.00'))
Decimal('50.00')
```

Comment: But why not just `str`? Is there a compelling reason to user `Decimal.quantize` over `str`?

Comment: @ChristianDean because `str` is not guaranteed to give 2 decimal places.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't know that.