# Python isn't displaying recurring decimals correctly?

Tags: python

I wanted python to display recurring decimals, so I tried the normal division code, but that only displayed about 10 digits. I wanted more, so I tried using the decimal module and this was the code:

```
from decimal import *
def divide(x,y)
      return(x/y)
print(Decimal(divide(10,3)))
input()
```

This gave more digits, but for some reason the decimals are wrong. This is what was displayed:

```
3.333333333333333481363069950020872056484222412109375
```

It stops recurring after a while and I have no idea why. Is Python unable to produce a large number of recurring decimals, or is something wrong with my code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Have a look at fixed point decimals:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45136821/how-to-convert-float-to-fixed-point-decimal-in-python

Comment: You passed a `float` to your `Decimal`, don't do that. Use a string

Comment: So do something like `print(divide(Decimal(10), Decimal(3)))` if you want to input a decimal number, use a string, not a float